# Reading Date and time exception

Tags: java, android

I want to read date and time from a device using joda.
I am doing BCD to String conversion and I am trying to read date and time like this :

```
String s = BCDtoASCII(resultBuff, 6, 8, false);
DateTime dt = new DateTime
(
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 4))),  // year
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(4, 2))),     // month
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6, 2))),     // day
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8, 2))),     // hour
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(10, 2))),    // minute
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(12, 2)))// seconds
);
```

But I am getting this exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14838
>       Process: com.calculator.gent.bluetoothcommuncation, PID: 17683 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; regionStart=4;  regionLength=-2
>       at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:504)
>       at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1333)

Answer (score 2):

As stated here in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) the first parameter is the start index and the second the end index and not the length.

So you have to do something like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(s.substring(4, 6));
```

Comment: I'm starting from 0 and read the year which has 4 digits, then start from 4 and read month with 2 digits and so on... I dont see any problem here.

Comment: Thanks Flown, after I had a look to the Javadoc, I got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
String s = BCDtoASCII(resultBuff, 6, 8, false);
DateTime dt = new DateTime
(
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, 4))),  // year
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(4, 6))),     // month
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(6, 8))),     // day
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8, 10))),     // hour
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(10, 12))),    // minute
(Integer.parseInt(s.substring(12, 14)))     // seconds
);
```